# 2-S or 3-S USB type-c PD LiPo battery charger

Tags: batteries, lipo, usb-c, bms

I am trying to implement a 2-S or 3-S USB type-c Power Delivery (USB-C PD) battery charger.
I am using this video of [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W13HNsoHj7A&t=906s) which uses a 16pin female usb type-c connector (part: [TYPE-C-31-M-12](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2205251630_Korean-Hroparts-Elec-TYPE-C-31-M-12_C165948.pdf)) and a USB C Power Delivery Controller ([CYPD3177-24LQXI](https://www.mouser.mx/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_EZ_PD_BCR_Datasheet_USB_Type_C_Port_Contr-3161917.pdf)) which has a well documented datasheet for implementation.
The schematic shows some PFETS for charging the battery (power subsystem block in Figure 3) But I have a doubt:
How could I implement this component for a 2-S or 3-S LiPo Battery charger (also for protection of the voltage higher limit: overcharge, overdischarge, overcurrent)?

[image]

Comment: The part you mention just handles DC-DC conversion from USB or a barrel jack, I can't find anything related to battery charging. I confess I've not watched the video, because 30 minutes is too long.

Comment: You can get the device to negotiate a higher voltage from the USB port, e.g. 20V and use it to drive the charging circuit or you can use a boost converter to go from 5V to whatever the charging circuit needs. You can get chips that combine some of these functions. The P-MOSFETs here are just for switching.

Comment: @Finbarr thank you, I will look for some of those IC's